# Menu com PHP e MySql

Tags: php, html, jquery, mysql, css

Criei uma um sistema de navegação para meu site. Vejam:

```html
<nav class="navegacao" id="navegacao">
  <ul class="menus">
    <li><a href="#">Categoria 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Categoria 2</a>
      <ul class="submenus">
        <li><a href="#">Sub-categoria 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub-categoria 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub-categoria 3</a>
          <ul class="submenus">
            <li><a href="#">Sub-categoria 1-1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub-categoria 1-2</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Categoria 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Deixei esse sistema de navegação Dinâmico criando uma função em PHP chamada listar_categorias() que gera a navegação usando MySql. Vejam:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Funcionou!!

Só tem um problema que não estou conseguindo resolver, esta sendo adicionado o trecho `<ul class="submenu"></ul>` mesmo não tendo nada pra listar dentro dele.

Alguém pode me ajudar a resolver?

Desde já, obrigado!

Answer (score -1):

Na linha 18 do seu código, você está escrevendo o "ul", antes de saber se existem sub categorias. Isso é um problema da lógica.

Isso é comum pq vc não está separando a lógica do negócio da visualização, o ideal é vc montar toda a estrutura de categorias em memória (em um array p. ex.) e escrever em tela em outra função.

Estude sobre MVC e vários outros problemas q vc pode ter com essa mistura de competências tbm vão ser resolvidos.

Obs.: Na próxima dúvida não poste o print do seu código, mas seu código direto usando às funções de formatação do site.

Comment: Valeu!! Eu ainda estou começando a postar as coisas aqui, então ainda não estou acostumado. Mas na próxima vou fazer isso sim!

Ahhh, e sobre o Array, eu fiz uma versão, mas não sei porque só esta gerando 1 nível. Vou ver se coloca aqui pra você ver